# Index was outside the bounds of the array error, TextBox7.Text = dr[1].ToString();

Tags: c#-4.0, ado.net, sqldatareader

I don't understand this error,i am new in c# and is the first time i see this error,can you help me with an idea?

```
cn.Open();
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmerPacienti from Outpacient WHERE PacientId ='" + 
                                DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", cn);
SqlDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    TextBox4.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    TextBox7.Text = dr[1].ToString();
}
dr.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query only returns one single column (`EmerPacienti`) but you're referencing a second column (`dr[1]`).